# Handling internal reprojections for geoprocessing using R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, epsg, function

Suppose I want to create a tool/function that has to, e.g., create buffers or measure distances internally to produce an output with a geographic projection.

How do I ensure that the distance computations are correct given that a user might provide an input dataset with geographic coordinates?

For example, I might provide a dataset with EPSG:4277 as its coordinate reference system. If no re-projections are performed, the distance calculations are likely to be wrong.

If I re-project to EPSG:27700, the distance calculations would be correct, but is it reasonable to try to re-project internally and if so, how can I find out which projected CRS is a good match for a given geographic CRS?

I am aware of an R package called `crsuggest`, which tries to suggest a projected CRS based on input coordinates, but I feel like this is not designed for automated workflows.

Comment: Please decide whether it is Python or R that you wish to ask about in this particular question.

Comment: This was intended to be a more general design question for GIS programming, but I couldn't find a fitting tag. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: This is a bit of a discussive "it depends" question. It depends on what you are doing, and how accurate you want to be. You can do everything (distances, buffers, etc) in geographic coordinates with spherical geometry so you don't need to transform.